# Do we want to have automatic tag deletion?

Tags: discussion, tags

The standard on all SE sites, unless they request otherwise, is that [single-use tags are deleted after 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48417/184716). There are some sites that have this disabled, particularly those which tend to have a lot of low-use tags.

That's exactly the category we fall in to, with over half of our titles as single-use. These aren't necessarily bad tags; most are about a particular series, and there's not much else they could be tagged with besides the series tag. Those tags will get deleted, and the questions will become tagged as [untagged](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) in most cases.

**Should we keep this auto-deletion script on, or request for it to be disabled on our site?**

**Note**: This question is intended as a poll; please upvote the answer you agree with, but do not downvote the other one. If you have more to add to the discussion, feel free to write your own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed - it's disabled here.

As usual, keep an eye on [the list of new tags](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) for crap.

Comment: Thank you Shog, I'll have this answer accepted soon.

Answer (score 12):

**We should request for the script to be disabled.**

This will prevent lots of correct tags from being deleted, but we'll need to actively police our tag list to make sure that invalid tags don't catch on and delete new ones which are clearly bad tags.

Comment: I cast my own vote for this one.

Comment: It'll be hard to keep track of all the ones that are deleted, this was is probably less effort for all involved

Answer (score 1):

**We should keep the script enabled.**

This will delete some bad tags after 6 months of disuse, but we'll need to regularly re-edit the good tags (including series tags) back on to questions which become untagged.

Comment: I think the script should be enabled, we can challenge users to make new questions for tags they want to be kept, like how [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/400/lets-save-our-tags) and [Board and Card Games](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/942/lets-save-our-tags) currently do. It might help generate more questions for the site as well, and maybe also weed out niche topics.

Comment: @Krazer: How should we tag the questions about one-shot stories? Or do we want those at all?

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't see why we can't have those. Just tagging it with the name is fine, but if a one-shot shares the name of another story/series, we can try tagging it with the author name.

Comment: @Krazer One-shot series tend to have fewer question - and in the case it is only used once, it will trigger the tag deletion script.

Comment: @nhahtdh we can try tagging one-shots with the author names then, but if we do this we have to make sure the title of the work is in the title.

Comment: @Krazer: Why not challenge users to make new questions for tags they want to be kept even with the script disabled? It may not always work out with having people to ask multiple questions about a subject.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I don't see why not, but I feel that there might be more motivation when the threat of elimination looms over them. Use it... or lose it!

Comment: @Krazer One of the first tags likely to get deleted is [tag:spirited-away]. I don't have any other questions about it, and I don't see any reason why the tag should go (leaving the question untagged), so I'll just edit it back on after it gets deleted. I suspect cases like this will be far more common than cases of neglected series that will suddenly get more questions to keep the tag alive.